# MySQL: How to use partial matches across rows to set the final value to NULL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with partial duplicate rows and I want to use the partial matches across the rows to set a value to NULL.

In this particular case, if the 'Name', 'Age', and 'Profession' columns are the same and the 'School' column is different, I want to set the 'School' column to NULL.

This is what my table looks like now:

```
Name    Age    Profession    Salary    School
John    21     Teacher       50,000    A
Lisa    24     Engineer      75,000    B
John    21     Teacher       55,000    C
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
Name    Age    Profession    Salary    School
John    21     Teacher       50,000    NULL
Lisa    24     Engineer      75,000    B
John    21     Teacher       55,000    NULL
```

How can I create a query that does this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to update the partial duplicate rows to store null, or you just want a query to report null?

Comment: If the latter, what do you want for salary if they don't match?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there should be some kind of primary key in your table.  That lacking, we can try the following update join approach:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, Age, Profession
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Name, Age, Profession
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t2.Name = t1.Name AND
       t2.Age = t1.Age AND
       t2.Profession = t1.Profession
SET
    School = NULL;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm working with a temporary table so I'm getting Error Code 1137, which is not allowing me to reopen the table. How can I work around this? I tried to create a clone of the temp table, but it still won't work.

Comment: Why are you working with temp tables, and could you settle for a select or view which displays the output as you have given it above?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Age, Profession, Salary,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(School) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Age, Profession) = 1
            THEN School
            END AS School
FROM sourcetable
```